# Change final shipping rate based on the product weight in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I am using **`table rate`** for shipping methods configuration.

[image]

But the final shipping rate will  change based on the product weight.

**Final shipping rate=Shipping rate*Product weight**

For Ex: If the prdouct weight=6kg,Final shipping rate will be 6*100
if the prdouct weight=11kg,Final shipping rate will be 11*90.

How can i achieve this feature?

Comment: I think that it's not possible with table rates, because those rates are flat. You probably should write your own module for calculating shipping fee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do a modification on this file

**`app/code/Magento/OfflineShipping/Model/Carrier/Tablerate.php`**

change line 166 from,

```
$shippingPrice = $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($rate['price']);
```

to

```
$shippingPrice = ($rate['price']*$request->getPackageWeight());
```